# YANG: How can I include a container from another module?

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I am writing a YANG module where I want to include a container from another module i.e. I want to define a NEW container in the module that I am writing that references a container from another module. Example of failed attempt:

```
 module newmodule {
 yang-version 1.1;
 namespace "urn:nist:params:xml:ns:yang:newmodule";
 prefix newmodule;

    import ietf-access-control-list {
      prefix "acl";
    }

    container newprofile {
      uses acl:access-lists;
    }
  }
```

I have only included the essential parts above. Here acl:access-lists is a container.

Is it possible to compose containers like this? I've tried successfully to build containers from groupings. However, in this case I have no control over the contents of ietf-access-control-list.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, besides groupings, you should also take a look at the `augment` statement. It allows injection of your schema nodes into an existing schema node hierarchy, which is what that container you tried referencing in the example is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the first module in the second one, then augment the first with the second:

Let's say the first module contains:

```
module first {
  yang-version 1.1;
  namespace "http://first";
  prefix first;

  container first-container {
    description
      "First container";
}
```

The second module shall have

```
module second {
  yang-version 1.1;
  namespace "http://second";
  prefix second;

  import first {
    prefix first;
  }

  augment "/first:first-container" {
    container second-container {
      description
        "Second container";
    }
  }
}
```

[YANG 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-4.2.8) allows that operation:

> YANG allows a module to insert additional nodes into data models,
> including both the current module (and its submodules) and an
> external module.  This is useful, for example, for vendors to add
> vendor-specific parameters to standard data models in an
> interoperable way.
>
> The "augment" statement defines the location in the data model
> hierarchy where new nodes are inserted, and the "when" statement
> defines the conditions when the new nodes are valid.

Comment: What this does is _insert_ a `second:second-container` node _into_ the `first:first-container`. The xpath for that inserted node would be `/first:first-container/second:second-container`. The `second` module itself has no actual nodes. In other words, this does not create a new augmented container inside the `second` module.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently not possible. You can only use a grouping in this fashion and not a container.